# How to get user details from native twitter app installed on device using Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I have implemented twitter login in my iOS app using FSHTwitterEngine. I have also implemented functionality to check for system account using ACAccountStore.

Before user log in through both, on button press, How can I check if user has already logged in to twitter native app, and if so get the user data from over there, then come back to my app.
(Same as FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative for facebook.)

```
  BOOL twInstalled = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"twitter://"]];

  if (twInstalled)
  {
        // here I want to check for the user if he/she is logged in and get data.
  }
  else
  {
    [self twitterLoginWithsystemAccount]

    // or

    [self twitterLoginWithFHSTwitterEngine];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accounts lastObject];
```

From above code you can check if user have twitter accounts in his phone using ACAccountStore.

Comment: This one is for getting detail from system account in device setting. I want to get detail from installed twitter app.